# where does app.use points to in my code?

Tags: node.js

i am a beginner and i cant really understand where does it point to and what does it mean by this particular line of code

**app.use('/api/v1', router);**

specially /api/v1 i am running this on my windows machine .

```
`'use strict';

const express    = require('express');        
const app        = express();                
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger       = require('morgan');
const router       = express.Router();
const port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger('dev'));

require('./routes')(router);
app.use('/api/v1', router);

app.listen(port);

console.log(`App Runs on ${port}`);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code:

```
app.use('/api/v1', router);
```

means that you are installing a router that will only be consulted for URLs whose path starts with `/api/v1` and any routes in the router will then be relative from that starting point.

So, if your router looks like this:

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', ...);
router.get('/list', ...);

module.exports = router;
```

And that's the router that you added with `app.use('/api/v1', router);`, then you would have a router for the URLs:

```
/api/v1
/api/v1/list
```

These paths are all in addition to whatever host your server is on.  So a full URL to initiate a request from the outside would include the host (either IP address or DNS name) such as:

```
http://example.com/api/v1
http://192.168.1.29/api/v1/list
```

The host is not needed when defining routes because the host name has already been processed by the time the request gets to your route handlers.

---

Keep in mind how http works.  When you enter a url such as `http://example.com/api/v1/list` in the browser, here's what the browser does.

1. It parses the URL and breaks it up into multiple pieces.  It finds a protocol of `http`, a host of `example.com` a path of `/api/v1/list` and finds no port specified.
2. With no port specified, it assumes the default port for the specified protocol.  The default port for `http` is port 80.
3. Now it takes that host `example.com` and looks it up in DNS to get an IP address.
4. Then, it makes a TCP connection to that IP address and the desired port.
5. When the TCP connection is established, it sends the HTTP request which can look like this.

Example:

```
GET /api/vi/list HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Cookie: x=y
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
Host: example.com
```

You will notice in that http request, the path is sent without the domain because the domain has already been used to get the IP address and make a connection to that host.

Answer (score 0):

it means that the given router will be used when a request comes to '/api/v1'
it's done to decompose your application into different independent modules .

you might want to check the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: ok i dont understand that it works fine without 10.0.2.2/api/v1 because in client that is android code I am using the code http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/v1/

Comment: so does /api/v1 already mean that and what will I use if my server is hosted on say some ip like 143.30.15.103 would it be like 143.30.15.103:say 3000 and then api/v1

Comment: the app.use(route, router) statement simply means that whenever a request comes to route it will be handled by router